# Converting HTML in a pandas dataframe column which was read from a csv file to Plain text

Tags: python, pandas, html-parsing, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which has two columns: 
One column with HTML and small formatting tags like br and &nbsp in it and another column named USEFUL.

I want to convert the HTML column to plain text without the "br" tags and &nbsp's. The HTML may contain other formatting tags as well, so using regular expression is not an option.
Apologize for not providing a data frame look. My formatting is really bad.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

#### Method 1:

According to this [link](https://rushter.com/blog/python-fast-html-parser/), this method is faster than method 2. It requires installing the `selectolax` module (use: `pip install selectolax`). You can find further examples of using this module in [here](https://github.com/rushter/selectolax/tree/master/examples).

```py
from selectolax.parser import HTMLParser

df['string_in_HTML']=data.apply(lambda x: HTMLParser(x['HTML']).body.text(separator=' ').replace('\n',' '),axis=1)
```

#### Method 2:

This is the most popular method I have come across in SO and requires installing `bs4` module (use: `pip install bs4`)

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

df['string_in_HTML']=data.apply(lambda x: BeautifulSoup(x['HTML']).get_text().replace('\n',' '),axis=1)
```